# Scrolling the window to place a div at mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, html

I've got an expand/collapse situation, which inserts/removes a significant chunk of content onto a page. That ~1800 vertical pixels disappearing has a disorienting effect, as suddenly my user will find himself way down the page in an area where previously he may not even have been.

So, following the 'collapse' click, I'd like the 'expand' div to be at the position where the 'collapse' div was previously.

Now, I can obtain the coordinates of the mouse when an item gets clicked:

```
var btnCollapse = document.getElementById('detail-collapse');
var btnExpand = document.getElementById('detail-expand');

btnCollapse.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('expand button at page Y ' + btnExpand.offsetTop);
    console.log('collapse button at page Y ' + e.pageY);
    console.log('clicked at window Y ' + e.clientY); 
});
```

Using `btnExpand.scrollIntoView()` feels too inaccurate. I want the expand div at an exact spot.
Using `.scrollBy(0,1800)` (or -1800) or `.scroll(0,5000)` all don't really yield the result I am looking for. The window keeps jumping further down the page.

What magical call do I need to be making to make this happen?

(PS. Using vanilla js, prefer not to introduce libraries as otherwise nothing is done in js)